# returning only specific rows on a Mysql query

Tags: mysql

My application is a video game I'm writing and I'm trying to write a script to move my creatures around the map.
so I am trying to return unique spawn_id,posx,posy combinations (only 1 row per unique combination)  It doesn't matter which one is returned id is my key field.

```
SELECT id,spawn_id,posx,posy,land,movelimit,next_turn FROM `game_moblist` WHERE 1 GROUP BY spawn_id,posx,posy
```

so given the data

```
id spawn_id posx posy
1  1        55   55
2  1        55   55
3  1        110  55
```

the query should return rows 1 and 3 (or 2 and 3 doesn't really matter) but not 1,2, and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
SELECT
    spawn_id, posx, posy, MIN(id) AS Id
FROM
    game_moblist
GROUP BY
    spawn_id, posx, posy
```

You could also just return the list of IDs, and then join against that in other queries:

```
SELECT
    MIN(id) AS Id
FROM
    game_moblist
GROUP BY
    spawn_id, posx, posy
```